# Chrome Packaged Apps / pdf.js

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to develop a (offline) packaged apps with chrome 23+ which allows the user to generate and print a pdf-file. I tried various ways to achieve this, but none really works.

Using something like this, the browser/app freezes:

```
window.html (includes pdf.js (http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) and genpdf.js (see below)):

....
<browser src="about:blank" width="1024" height="768"></browser>

genpdf.js:

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'foo');
doc.text(20, 30, 'bar');
document.querySelector('browser').src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(new Blob([doc.output()], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
```

This would be my preferred way to display the generated PDF, but with the window freezing the user can't print it.

Another way would be to save the PDF to the desktop:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseFile({type: 'saveFile'}, function(writableFileEntry) {
    writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
      writer.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log('writeend');
      };
      writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log('writeend');
      };
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.text(20, 20, 'foo');
      doc.text(20, 30, 'bar');
      writer.write(new Blob([doc.output()], {type: 'application/pdf'}));
    }, errorHandler);
});
```

This works, but the file on the desktop is locked until the app is closed. Is there any api-call i'm missing to free the saved file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would love to see someone answer this.

Comment: If your preferred solution is causing Chrome to crash, the first thing I would do is [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list). It's quite possible the Chrome devs can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

In the second solution I believe you should provide the buffer size, so the writer will be able to know when the write is ended.

```
var docBuffer = doc.output();
writer.write(new Blob([docBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf', 'size': docBuffer.length}));
```

Comment: I wouldn't say your answer solves the problem, but it sure gets us closer to debugging it.

Comment: Yes, you right! If the op provides some more information I would like to help

Answer (score -1):

Take a sneak peak to [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/%20wkhtmltopdf), it generates PDF from a HTML+CSS page using WebKit engine. I love it, it produces pixel same result as page appears in Chromium browser. There're version for MS-Windows and Linux, I've tried both.

Comment: The OP is looking for an in-browser method, specifically using Chrome Apps, not a utility based on webkit.

Comment: This does not at all address the question asked, as Knownasilya notes.

Comment: Sometimes it costs less effort to change the problem than solve it. I'm not familiar with *packaged apps*, but if they can launch external executable, maybe it's a faster solution. Also, when PDF is generated from HTML the template can be edited by a web designer, the result layout will be more professional.

Comment: I don't think we even know that he is generating a pdf of a website specifically.. Maybe he is..